# toLocaleTimeString() always showing leading zero

Tags: javascript

I would like to display this as something like: **4:26 PM**.

But what I keep getting is: **04:26 PM**.

If I remove the hour and minute `options` from `toLocaleTimeString()`, it works, but it also displays seconds, which I don't want.

```js
myClock();
function myClock() { 
    var d = new Date().toLocaleTimeString([], {hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit'});   
    document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = d; 
}
setInterval(myClock, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="clock"></div>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're setting the `2-digit` format for hours; sounds like you want `numeric` instead:

```js
myClock();
function myClock() { 
    var d = new Date().toLocaleTimeString([], {hour: 'numeric', minute:'2-digit'});   
    document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = d; 
}
setInterval(myClock, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="clock"></div>
```

(Note that this may depend on the specific locale; the above is true for `en-US`.  The [rules](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4647#section-3.4) for determining the locale when not explicitly specified are in part based on individual user settings; if you need everyone to see the exact same formatting, you may want to substitute `en-US` in place of the first argument to `toLocaleTimeString`.  (Though of course that defeats the purpose of having locales in the first place!)

Comment: I'm seeing `09:02` (good morning!) on both Firefox and Chrome. Did something change in browsers implementations of this? (also hardcoding the `en-US` locale, just in case)

Comment: @RobinMétral am not seeing the leading zero on Chrome/Edge on Windows10 or on IOS Safari but am seeing it on Firefox Windows10.

Comment: Thanks @AHaworth. Probably variation in implementations, then. Which is strange, because I couldn't find anything about it (in docs, web platform tests, browser support data, etc)

Comment: For what it's worth, on OSX I'm seeing correct behavior in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox: `hour: '2-digit'` includes the leading 0, `hour: 'numeric'` omits it (though this may vary by locale of course.) @RobinMétral and @AHaworth are you seeing the leading 0 when `hour: 'numeric'` is set in `en-US`?

Comment: No, not in en-US on my side. I think it's locale. Working on a small repro CodeSandbox right now to share results here afterwards :)

Comment: This whole thing made me realize that although my browser locale (`navigator.locale`) is "en", my Intl locale (`(new Intl.NumberFormat()).resolvedOptions().locale`) is "en-DE" (and I don't know why)

Comment: Ah, yeah then.  I'll admit I don't know the nuances of how each locale handles these options, but then again the whole point of having locales is so we don't need to :)  I'll update the answer to make that clearer, thanks!

Comment: Yup, this is exactly my learning here: don't expect to know exactly what'll come out of `toLocaleTimeString()` (unless hardcoding a locale) and trust `Intl.DateTimeFormat`. An illustrative example: https://codesandbox.io/s/datetimeformat-locale-fun-fx4hf3?file=/src/index.js