# toLocaleTimeString() with "numeric" minutes always showing leading zero

Tags: javascript

If this seems similar to the other question "[toLocaleTimeString() always showing leading zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66268522/tolocaletimestring-always-showing-leading-zero)", that's because it is.

I want to format a time string to `mm:ss` without a leading zero for minutes, like **9:09**. However, I'm only getting **09:09** when using [`Date.toLocaleTimeString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString).

The difference with the question that I linked above is that I'm already using `minute: "numeric"` in my [`DateTimeFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat) options:

```js
const date = new Date(Date.now());
date.setMinutes(9,9); // so we're sure to catch leading zeros

const timeOptions = {
  minute: "numeric", // without leading zero
  second: "2-digit", // with leading zero
}

const dateString = date.toLocaleTimeString("en-US", timeOptions)

// ❌ I expect "9:09", I get "09:09"
console.log(dateString);
```

Interestingly, when changing options to get *only* numeric minutes (no seconds), it works as expected:

```js
const date = new Date(Date.now());
date.setMinutes(9,9); // so we're sure to catch leading zeros

const timeOptions = {
  minute: "numeric", // without leading zero
  // second: "2-digit", //  without seconds this time!
}

const dateString = date.toLocaleTimeString("en-US", timeOptions)

// ✅ I expect "9", I get "9"
console.log(dateString);
```

I've been through the full MDN docs on `DateTimeFormat` and couldn't find anything to explain this. I've also tried this on the latest Chrome and Firefox, with the same results.

So my question(s):

- is it just me? (e.g. could it be a localization issue? I'm explicitly setting the locale to `en-US` in my example to try to avoid this, but who knows)
- how can I get this to work?

Comment: I also get 09 on your first example, using Safari IOS. I did not get the zero when running the accepted answers snippet in your link. So it’s got to be the bit you added.

Comment: Yup, turns out the difference was that the linked question was formatting `hh:mm` while I am formatting `mm:ss`. Foolish of me to think that they would behave consistently :P More at https://codesandbox.io/s/datetimeformat-locale-fun-fx4hf3?file=/src/index.js (I'll add details in an answer)

Comment: Weird, but I learned something!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it just me? (e.g. could it be a localization issue? I'm explicitly
> setting the locale to en-US in my example to try to avoid this, but
> who knows)

I don't think it's the localization. It just works that way.

> how can I get this to work?

Maybe it's overkill, but not long ago I created a [small library](https://github.com/KooiInc/dateformat) to format dates using [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat). It does the trick because it utilizes the parts of `formatToParts`, see snippet.

```html
<script type="module">
  const dtFormat = (await 
    import(`//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/intl-dateformatter@latest/index.min.js`))
    .default;
  const date2Format = new Date();
  date2Format.setHours(9);
  date2Format.setMinutes(9);
  console.log( dtFormat(date2Format, `h:mmi`, `l:en-US`) );
</script>
```

To be more clear: here's what `formatToParts` returns.

```js
const now = new Date();
now.setHours(9);
now.setMinutes(9);
const opts = {hour: `numeric`, minute: `2-digit`};
const formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', opts);
console.log(formatter.formatToParts(now));
```

Check some experiments with the library @[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-5wqvwc?file=script.js).

Comment: You're right: after some more testing (https://codesandbox.io/s/datetimeformat-locale-fun-fx4hf3?file=/src/index.js) I realized that in `en-US`, an `mm:ss` pair will always have a leading zero. What threw me off is that an `hh:mm` does _not_ have a leading zero and I was expecting a consistent behavior between the two. Thanks for your answer! (I'll post my own answer with more findings)

Answer (score 1):

*(Note: I'm accepting [Kooilnc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75775017) since it was correct and shared a helpful library to help format dates in a more predictable way. This is meant to add some more detailed findings about and `Date` and localization.)*

---

### `DateTimeFormat` options work in mysterious ways

The first thing I missed when asking this question is that I misunderstood `DateTimeFormat` options. The `day`, `hour`, `minute` and `second` options accept the following values (example for [the day option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat#day)):

> `day`
>
> The representation of the day. Possible values are:
>
> - `"numeric"` (e.g., 1)
> - `"2-digit"` (e.g., 01)

As a result, I assumed that to **format minutes and seconds without a leading 0 for minutes**, the following would work (snippet copied from the question):

```js
const date = new Date(Date.now());
date.setMinutes(9,9); // so we're sure to catch leading zeros

const timeOptions = {
  minute: "numeric", // without leading zero
  second: "2-digit", // with leading zero
}

const dateString = date.toLocaleTimeString("en-US", timeOptions)

// ❌ I expect "9:09", I get "09:09"
console.log(dateString);
```

This does *not* work, and that's because these properties (`day`, `hour`, `minute`, `second`) don't behave consistently, especially when grouped in specific subsets.

For example:

```js
const date = new Date(Date.now());
date.setHours(9,9,9); // so we're sure to catch leading zeros

// consistent options
const minuteAndSecond = {
  minute: "numeric",
  second: "2-digit",
}
const hourAndMinute = {
  hour: "numeric",
  minute: "2-digit",
}

// inconsistent formatting (even in the same locale)
console.log(date.toLocaleTimeString("en-US", minuteAndSecond)); //  09:09
console.log(date.toLocaleTimeString("en-US", hourAndMinute)); //  9:09 AM
```

So as [Kooilnc wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75775017), while this can seem inconsistent, this is just how `DateTimeFormat` options work.

---

### A side note about locale

When I stumbled on the [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66268522/) that I linked to, I was surprised to see that the accepted solution wasn't working for me:

```js
const date = new Date(Date.now());
date.setHours(9,9); // so we're sure to catch leading zeros

const timeOptions = {
  hour: "numeric", // without leading zero
  minute: "2-digit", // with leading zero
}

const dateString = date.toLocaleTimeString([], timeOptions)

//  the question said this would be "9:09 AM", I was getting "09:09"
console.log(dateString);
```

I had missed a couple important things:

- first, as mentioned above, options for formatting **hours and minutes** don't behave like options for formatting **minutes and seconds**. So the other question's solution doesn't apply to my question
- in the other question's case, the reason that I was getting a leading zero was indeed because of locale. The snippet passes `[]` as `Date.toLocaleTimeString()`'s first parameter, so the browser uses the default locale. I won't go into details here, but the *tl;dr* is: my browser's locale resolved to `en-DE` (not `en-US`), therefore I was seeing hours and minutes formatted differently. Iff you're interested, I did a few formatting experiments in [a CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/datetimeformat-locale-fun-fx4hf3?file=/src/index.js).

So: locale *is* an important factor for formatting hours and minutes, but it didn't affect my case of formatting minutes and seconds (although it might have, with yet other locales).

---

### In closing (where do we go from here)

I've personally decided to not remove the leading zero from the formatted time after all. Attempting to force a localized time string to look a certain way seems at odds with the concept of localization itself.

My recommendation to others would be to treat the output of `Date.toLocaleDateTime()` like a random string (i.e. don't try to predict its format) and to trust the browser to format it in a way that makes the most sense for users. If you *absolutely* need to format a `Date` in a specific way, you're probably better off using something like [`Date.toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) (which outputs a predictable ISO format), and transforming the result at will.