# why is my footer blocking the page`s conrent

Tags: css, vue.js, footer

I am using a footer as a Vue component importing it into all the pages (views).
Unfortunately, it covers/blocks the bottom content of the page.
What shall I change in the CSS?

```
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color:#EB9BC3  ;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: What do you want to happen? Do you want it fixed at the bottom or not? If so, do you want the content above to be scrollable? We can't help I think on this small amount of code. Please create a snippet see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66268522/tolocaletimestring-always-showing-leading-zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second to what the comment above says. We need a bit more to assist you.

You could play with the Z-Index based on scroll, but I would recommend changing the positioning.

Ex

```
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left:0
}
```

or

```
.footer{
  position: relative:
  bottom: 0;
  left:0
}
```